# Is this proof that the subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit rigorous?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am working through Abbot's Understanding Analysis and I am confused about when a proof is rigorous enough to be acceptable. This is a proof I came up with to show that subsequences of convergent sequences converge to the same limit as the original sequence.

For a sequence $a_n$ and numbers $n_1<n_2<n_3<\ldots$ that are increasing natural numbers, the sequence
$$a_{n_1},a_{n_2},a_{n_3},\ldots$$
is a subsequence of $a_n$ denoted by $a_{n_j}$, where $j\in\mathbb{N}$ serves as an index for the subsequence. Note that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n\geq N$, it follows that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$, where $L$ is the limit of $a_n$. Because $n_j$ is a sequence of increasing natural numbers, there exists an $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_j\geq N$ whenever $j\geq M$. Thus for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $j\geq M$, it follows that $|a_{n_j}-L|<\epsilon$. Thus the subsequence converges to the same limit as the original sequence.

Does this constitute a rigorous proof? The only statement that I have doubts about is

> Because $n_j$ is a sequence of increasing natural numbers, there exists an $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_j\geq N$ whenever $j\geq M$.

I know this is true, but I came up with this statement using intuition. Should I continue writing proofs that rely on assumptions like this, or should I try to prove everything by referencing previously proved statements and axioms only? I feel that proving every intuitive statement such as this would hinder my ability to learn the material in the book.

Comment: I think the proof is fine. With regard to the highlighted statement, certainly there exists a $M \in \mathbb N$ such that $n_M \geq N$, because there are infinitely many distinct $n_j$ but only finitely many natural numbers smaller than $N$. Then we have $n_j > n_M \geq N$ whenever $j > M$.